# Windows service temp. files for another user

Tags: windows, services

Where to store temp files for a windows service running as another user.
The `Temp` folder by default is:

```
- Temp: C:\WINDOWS\TEMP
- Temp: C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp
```

But the user who runs the service has no write permissions in these folders.
What is the best/right way?

Comment: You say that the user has no `%AppData%` folder, but that's impossible. I guess that you have not created that user account using the Windows utilities, therefore this is not a real account.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `%AppData%\Local\Temp\`

Comment: The user has no %AppData% folder.
The user have no logged in anytime.

Comment: What user does the service login as? You might need to use `NT Authority\Network Service` then grant that user permissions on your `Temp` folder.

Comment: The user is a domain user who has certain rights on network drives. But he has no rights in the windows / system32 folder

Comment: @raiserle Shouldn't Windows automatically create a user profile on first "login" (login means the first time a process is executed using that account)?

Comment: If the solution is to create a profile for this user, this can be taken as a solution.
But, if I read the TEMP variable in the service, it points to ``C:\WINDOWS\TEMP``

Answer (score 0):

- Grant the domain user permissions for the location(s) in question
- or set the service to run as the local system account
- or set the service to run as a domain admin account